NMAP says host is down, but it's not
When running nmap -A -vvv 192.168.0.141 from host A I get the following result:
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
But running ping 192.168.0.141 is successful shows a >1ms latency between these hosts. I can even SSH into host B from host A.
Trying to scan host B from host A with -Pn also results in NMAP saying that host B is down.
Host A is a Windows 11 PC. Host B is an Ubuntu Server 24.04 VM running in VirtualBox on host A.
I have VirtualBox the single network interface set as "Bridged Adapter" and "Allow All".
What's going on here?
Edit: Firewall is disabled on host B. Both OSes are updated to the newest version. Reinstalling NMAP didn't work.

Can you provide any details regarding the network setup or system details?

If you want to change something you should describe the problem, not just the symptoms.

So ping is shpowing ICMP packets being delivered and NMAP is showing TCP/IP packets being rejected... that's probably what you have.

NMAP is reporting that IP could be blocking our ping probes - so, NMAP ping (i.e. ICMP) fails

Hi! How could NMAP report that TCP packets are being rejected when I can SSH into that VM? The packets are clearly going through, just not when they originate from NMAP :/

application firewall?

As mentioned in the post - firewall is off on host B

In the off chance it helps:
Since I don't usually have NMAP on a windows box, I usually now use their Test-NetConnection powershell command to check connectivity.
Next thought was on memory that Vbox may have had some rules blocking/limiting traffic, but you noted a "Bridged Adapter" set with "Allow All", so unlikely to be an issue there.
Have you by chance tried running NMAP against a specific port you know to be open to see its results?  Ie:  SSH, or a webserver?  Or even running NMAP from the localhost against itself.

Hey, first of all - thanks for your feedback. And yes: I have tried running nmap on a specific port that I know is open, but nmap still reports host B as being down. Running nmap on a Windows 11 VM (host C), running on host A, returns correct results when scanning host B.
Edit: Host C has the same VirtualBox network settings as host B - that is: "Bridged Adapter" and "Allow All"
